# Very basic ASP.net (accessing GET variables)

Tags: asp.net, variables, get

I am currently trying to learn ASP.net
But still having some nice n00b questions.

Hence I am asking them. Because I would like to master this coding language.

The current script gives me a compilation error

```
<%
Dim title as string = "My TITLE"
Request.QueryString["pageid"]

Select Case pageid
    Case "home"
        title = "Home"
    Case "info"
        title = "Info"
    Case "portfolio"
        title = "Portfolio"
    Case "contact"
        title = "Contact"
    Case Else
        title = "Home"
End Select
%>
```

It is a basic switch statement which shouldb be operated by GET.

This is the error that it generates :

**Compiler Error Message: BC30545: Property access must assign to the property or use its value.
Source Error:**

Comment: The compiler error is very clear. You are accessing a property (`Request.QueryString["pageid"]`) and doing nothing with it.

Comment: 1. Where did you ever see code like that, and 2. You shouldn't be putting logic in a page that way. That's the same way as was done in Ancient Days with Classic ASP.

Comment: 3. I've never heard the term "GET variable" before, either.

Comment: probably should be pageid = Request.QueryString["pageid"]

Comment: and it looks like classical ASP

Answer (score 1):

Declaration for "pageid" variable is missing. When you get value from querystring, it should be assigned to string variable.

```
<%
Dim title as string = "My TITLE"
Dim pageid as string
pageid = Request.QueryString["pageid"]

Select Case pageid
    Case "home"
        title = "Home"
    Case "info"
        title = "Info"
    Case "portfolio"
        title = "Portfolio"
    Case "contact"
        title = "Contact"
    Case Else
        title = "Home"
End Select
%>
```